# Notice: Undefined index in select Option tag PHP

Tags: php, html

> Notice : Undefined index in Select option tag

When i open this program on browser, the error "undefined index" appear in SELECT option (drop-down box). 
Help me friends

```
<label>Your location<span class="error">*</span>:</label>
    <select name="loca">
      <option label="Select"></option>
      <option <?php if($_POST["loca"] == "Andaman and Nicobar Islands") echo "selected"; ?>>Andaman and Nicobar Islands</option>
      <option <?php if($_POST["loca"] == "Andhra Pradesh") echo "selected"; ?>>Andhra Pradesh</option>
      <option <?php if($_POST["loca"] =="Arunachal Pradesh") echo "selected"; ?>>Arunachal Pradesh</option>
      <option <?php if($_POST["loca"] =="Assam") echo "selected"; ?>>Assam</option>
      <option <?php if($_POST["loca"] == "Bihar") echo "selected"; ?>>Bihar</option>
      <option <?php if($_POST["loca"] == "Chandigarh") echo "selected"; ?>>Chandigarh</option>
      <option <?php if($_POST["loca"] =="Chhattisgarh") echo "selected"; ?>>Chhattisgarh</option>
      <option <?php if($_POST["loca"] =="Dadra and Nagar Haveli") echo "selected"; ?>>Dadra and Nagar Haveli </option>
      <option <?php if($_POST["loca"] =="Daman and Diu") echo "selected"; ?>>Daman and Diu</option>
      <option <?php if($_POST["loca"] =="Goa") echo "selected"; ?>>Goa</option>
      <option <?php if($_POST["loca"] =="Gujarat") echo "selected"; ?>>Gujarat</option>
      <option <?php if($_POST["loca"] =="Haryana") echo "selected"; ?>>Haryana</option>
      <option <?php if($_POST["loca"] =="Himachal Pradesh") echo "selected"; ?>>Himachal Pradesh</option>
      <option <?php if($_POST["loca"] =="Jammu and Kashmir") echo "selected"; ?>>Jammu and Kashmir</option>
      <option <?php if($_POST["loca"] =="Jharkhand") echo "selected"; ?>>Jharkhand</option>
      <option <?php if($_POST["loca"] =="Karnataka") echo "selected"; ?>>Karnataka</option>
      <option <?php if($_POST["loca"] =="Kerala") echo "selected"; ?>>Kerala</option>
      <option <?php if($_POST["loca"] =="Lakshadweep") echo "selected"; ?>>Lakshadweep</option>
      <option <?php if($_POST["loca"] =="Madhya Pradesh") echo "selected"; ?>>Madhya Pradesh</option>
      <option <?php if($_POST["loca"] =="Maharashtra") echo "selected"; ?>>Maharashtra</option>
   </select>
    <span class="error"><?php echo $locationErr?></span> <br />
```

Comment: because your variable $_POST["loca"] is not set at the first request. do <?php if(isset($_POST["loca"]) && $_POST["loca"] == "...")

Comment: it means `$_POST["loca"]` OR `$_POST` is not defined

Comment: Use `loop` to reduce redundant code.

Comment: Just a suggestion: You'd be better off creating an array of locations, then write a loop to output the options. It'd be a lot better for readability, and would be easier to maintain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's always better to add a  [isset](https://www.php.net/isset) check in such cases

better to write your conditions this way

```
if(isset($_POST["loca"]) && $_POST["loca"]  == "Andaman and Nicobar Islands") echo "selected";
```

Answer (score 0):

because your variable $_POST["loca"] is not set at the first request.

do `<?php if(isset($_POST["loca"]) && $_POST["loca"] == "...")`

Furthermore you should specify a value attribute on each option-tag.

Comment: then please mark it as solved, for someone in the future is facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

$ _POST ['Loca'] exists only if you submit the form, if not, initialize $ _POST ['loca'] like this: $ _POST ['loca'] = "";

```
/* Initialize var */

$_POST["loca"]="";
$locationErr="";

<label>Your location<span class="error">*</span>:</label>
<select name="loca">
// OPTION
</select>
```